# Issue filtering results from Alamofire by array item in swift4?

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

So using I am Alamofire and SwiftyJSON I am able to pull data from a JSON source and assign it to a tableview. What I need to do now is filter the results by date. The idea is to grab todays date and only show items that equal or are greater than todays date.

Using Alamofire now when I query the source I get the following

```
{
"mlb_schedule": {
    "columns": [
        "awayTeam",
        "homeTeam",
        "date",
        "time"
    ],
    "records": [
        [
            "TOR",
            "BOS",
            "7/14/18",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "KCA",
            "CHA",
            "7/14/18",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "TBA",
            "MIN",
            "7/14/18",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "MIL",
            "PIT",
            "7/14/18",
            ""
        ],
        [
            "ARI",
            "ATL",
            "7/14/18",
            ""
        ],
```

I created a getDate function to pull the current date and send. it to the var dateToday in the code below. Where my issue is exists in Alamofire where I can't seem to select the dict value to filter by the response as shown in the code below.

```
    var arrRes = [Any]()
public var baseballSelectedRow: [String] = []
var dateToday = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getDate()

    //Alamofire
    Alamofire.request("http://52.34.250.4/mlb/api.php/mlb_schedule").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

            if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["mlb_schedule"]["records"].arrayObject {
                self.arrRes = resData.filter { $0.dict[2] <= dateToday}
            }
            if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

func getDate() {
    let currentDate = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    let convertableDate = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate)
    dateToday = convertableDate
}
```

}
extension SwarmBaseballViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrRes.count
    }

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SwarmListTableViewCell") as? SwarmListTableViewCell {
        if let dict = arrRes[indexPath.row] as? [Any] {
            if dict.count > 2 {
                cell.awayLabel?.text = dict[0] as? String
                cell.homeLabel?.text = dict[1] as? String
                cell.dateLabel?.text = dict[2] as? String
                cell.timeLabel?.text = dict[3] as? String
            }
        }

        return cell
    } else {
        return SwarmListTableViewCell()
    }
}
```

I realize my syntax is wrong but, can't for the life of me find how/why?

Comment: `$0.dict[2] <= dateToday` you should not compare dates like this. First convert the date string to date and use `compare(:)` method on date.

Comment: `dict[0]` That's supposed to be a Dictionary according to the name but it's an Array (you access the value with index, not key). That's really misleading.

Comment: You're right I misspoke will edit thank you.

Comment: Are you responsible for the server side? This JSON structure saves a few bytes but is very inefficient. If yes send dictionaries including the keys – rather than separate keys and value arrays – and a UNIX timestamp or ISO8601 date string.  Then drop `SwiftyJSON` and decode the stuff with `Decodable`.